# How to manage the page transition in android xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, transition

I am working in xamarin forms app. I have created an app in which I am using Master detail page. The page transition is working fine in Master detail page. But when I try to open a simple content page that is not under Master detail page, the transition is very odd. When I move on simple content page from master detail page first the screen moves up and hide the Action bar and then screen come down and shows the new page. I want that when user try to open the content page the transition should smooth from right to left.
How I can manage page transitions between Master detail page and simple content page?

Comment: Please add a print screen of the code or paste part the code of the app.cs when you call the simple content page. I need to watch the code to help you. For a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your detail page in `NavigationPage`, so that the detail to next page navigation is not via `MasterDetail`.

Find the sample demo [here](https://github.com/rohitvipin/XFMasterDetailDemo).